# response.text() does not contain what i expect

Tags: html, dom, fetch

I have a mocked file mockedfile.html which I am redirecting to locally. My problem is that when I try to extract the HTML from the fetch response, the result does not look exactly like the mocked file. So this is what I do:

```js
fetch('/some-url.html').then(response => {
  if (response.redirected) { // this will be true locally
    fetch(response.url) // which will then be /mockedfile.html
      .then(res => res && res.text())
      .then(text => text) // expect this text to be the same as the content inside mockedfile.html, but this is just partly the same
  } else {
    response && response.text().then(text => text);
  }
}
})
```

What am I missing? Is there a more propper way to solve this?

Comment: .then(res => res && res.text()) - can you not do jut .then(res => res.text()) ?

Comment: no, because of res.text() is returning a promise, so I need to have the extra then(...)

Comment: No because the extra than does nothing except returning a new promise with the same value again

Comment: the code I posted works fine in our project, one of the potential gotchas is relative paths - you can open DEV console in chrome to see what network path has actually been probed.

Answer (score 0):

To get the values outside of your fetch, you need the first `.then()` return something.

The extra `.then()` is unnecessary, because it just creates a new promise resolving to the same value.

```js
fetch('/some-url.html')
  .then(response => {
    if (response.redirected) {
      return fetch(response.url)
        .then(res => res.text());
    }
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add *)* to close brace opened at *then(*

```
   fetch('/some-url.html').then(response => {
  if (response.redirected) { // this will be true locally
    fetch(response.url) // which will then be /mockedfile.html
      .then(res => res && res.text())
      .then(text => text) // expect this text to be the same as the content inside mockedfile.html, but this is just partly the same
  } else {
    response && response.text().then(text => text);
  }
});
})
```

Answer (score -1):

```
fetch(url).then(result => result.text()).then(yourText => ...);
```